# Tirar todas as TAGS html menor a quebra de linha

Tags: html, string

Minha dúvida é simples, eu acho.

Recebo via post a descrição:

```
    $descricao = strip_tags(mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['descricao'])));
```

E quando vou imprimir na tela uso:

```
    nl2br($foto_user_visitado->descricao)
```

Isso deveria imprimir na tela a descrição reconhecendo os "enter" mas como coloquei a função `strip_tags` ele não mostra. Como posso fazer? sendo que quero escapar todas as `tags` html.

Comment: Você pode adaptar o código usando htmlentities($str); invés de strip_tags e depois usar outros métodos para remover as tags.

Comment: Você quer manter quebras de linha ou as tags `br`?

Answer (score 1):

Se a quebra de linha for a tag `<br />` é so colocar um segundo parâmetro na função strip_tags e nele você vai indicar quais tags devem ser mantidas.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

//somente as tags <br> e <i> serão mantidas
$texto = strip_tags("<b>texto</b> com<br /><i>tags</i><br />html", '<br><i>');

echo $texto;
```

Vai retornar:

texto com
*tags*
html